# Solving with multiple entities

Tags: java, optaplanner, vehicle-routing, timefold

I'm currently working on solving a routing problem using OptaPlanner, and I'm facing a challenge regarding planning variables. For a specific planning entity, I'd like to use both a basic planning variable and a planning list variable (a total of 2 planning variables). Is it possible to combine these two types of planning variables within one planning entity?

So far, I've attempted to achieve this but encountered the following error message:

'The config (ValueSelectorConfig(null)) has no configured variableName for entityClass (class org.acme.routing.domain.T...) and because there are multiple variableNames ([assignedPosition, auftragsListe]), it cannot be deduced automatically.'

Could you please explain how I can resolve this issue or if there's a better approach?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, at the moment, list variable can not be combined with any other variable.
In the future, Timefold Solver will likely fix that.

Chained variable already does support co-existence with a basic planning variable.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have taken a closer look at the chapter on chained planning variables, and as far as I understand, it involves using multiple entities. However, since I only want to use a single entity, can I still model a chained planning variable?